# GridView rows all selected when page is loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView2, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
    }
}
```

Basically, when I refresh the page everytime the code inside of ^ Gets fired off, I am trying to make the rows inside of my grid view clickable to render a new page with information regarding that row. but for some reason on page load it will fire off for every single row.

Now I have tried us !isPostBack in the page load, the issue with this is that it prevents the rendering of gridview pages>2. I did also get to a point where a couple of if statements prevented the issue but the it required two clicks in order for the event to fire so I know I am doing something incorrectly and hope someone can help. just going to include my aspx and the c# code if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" CssClass="mydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="Gridpager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Gridheader" RowStyle-CssClass="Gridrows" 
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView2_PageIndexChanging" 
    PageSize="13"  width="100%" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnIndex" runat="server"
                    Value='<%# Eval("RecordID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Certificate" HeaderText="Number"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Company_Name" HeaderText="Bank Name"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone1" HeaderText="Phone"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address_Line_1" HeaderText="Street Address"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"  />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State"  />
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings  mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" PreviousPageText="Previous" NextPageText="Next" LastPageText="Last" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionStringGlobal;
    conn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Clients";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    conn.Close();

    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Lastly Pagination Code:

```
protected void GridView2_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

and here is the code for the row click

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Attaching one onclick event for the entire row, so that it will
        // fire SelectedIndexChanged, while we click anywhere on the row.
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
          ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView2, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);

    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your `Page_Load()` event from your code behind please? Actually, it would be great to see the full code behind to verify why isn't pagination working too.

Comment: @ Santiago Trejo, there you go. I did try with the !isPostBack argument but that seems to have kept my table from generating past the first page. Thanks for your time and help. as for the entirety of the code this is pretty much it except for my imports.

Comment: Check my aswer below please.

Answer (score 0):

The `GridView` is being loaded everytime the page refreshes or there's a `PostBack` so it's OK to load the data only when the page is loaded for the first time, also, we're saving the query results into a `Session` variable for later use on `PageIndexChanged` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( !Page.IsPostBack )
    {
        LoadData();
    }
}

protected void LoadData()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionStringGlobal;
    conn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Clients";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    conn.Close();

    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();   

    // Save into a session variable for later load on pagination.
    Session.Add("tmp_dt",dt);
}
```

Now we need to also load the data on the `GridView2_PageIndexChanging` event in order to pagination to work:

```
protected void GridView2_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{       
    // Load the data previously saved into a session variable.
    // You might want to read the database instead.
    DataTable dt = (DataTable) Session["tmp_dt"];
    this.GridView2.DataSource = dt;

    // Change the page index before databind. This differs from the LoadData() method.
    GridView2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

And at your `ASPX` code, add the `AllowPaging=True` property to the `GridView2` control.

Comment: This returns an error in regards to Session["tmp_dt"], tells me I cant implicitly  convert object type to datatable. Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Try just `dt = Session["tmp_dt"]; `

Comment: I am trying it like you have listed above, word for word. Still is giving me that error.

Comment: Ok I see the mistake instead of `DataTable dt = New DataTable;` it should be `DataTable dt = DataTable;`. I'll update the answer

Comment: I know I'm probably not the sharpest, but still returning the same error as above, and now the Datatable dt = DataTable; is returning "datatable is a type but is used like a variable" error. again thanks for working with me.

Comment: Now this looks to work amazingly, however whenever loading or reloading the page, each and every row gets called. and thus the function I have associated with it, it opens up 13 browsers. 

I will attach the code above for whoever to take a look at.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish on the `RowDataBound` event. Could you please explain? Thank you